# Setting up Git on EC2 to pull from GitHub repo

Tags: git, github, amazon-ec2

I'm kind of new to both EC2 and Git, and I have just set up my first instance of EC2, using a clean Amazon Linux AMI. I also installed MySQL, Apache and PHP and opened some ports to make it work as a normal web server, responding to an elastic IP as well.

Now, my code is on a private repo on GitHub, and I would like to perform simple deployments by doing `git pull` or something like that. Git is also installed on the server already. I know I could set up my git repo on the server using my personal ssh key, but it seems odd. I guess another solution would be to create a new GitHub user and use it on the server, but it doesn't seem right either.

How do I achieve this in an elegant, safe way?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To avoid having to keep an SSH private key on your EC2 instance, people often use a workflow that involves pushing to that remote server in order to deploy.  Essentially, you set up a bare git repository there with a `pre-receive` hook that deploys to another directory.  There is a simple example of doing this in [this tutorial](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto).  Then you only need to have your SSH *public* key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server.  However, with this workflow, you couldn't deploy directly from your GitHub repository - you would need to pull it locally and then push to the EC2 machine.

An alternative is to use GitHub's [deploy keys](http://help.github.com/deploy-keys/) mechanism.  This would involve creating a new SSH key-pair on your EC2 instance, and adding the public key as a deploy key into your private repository on GitHub.  Then you can pull directly from your private GitHub repository to your EC2 instance.

Answer (score 13):

I just solved such situation by following the [tutorial](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto) that [Mark Longair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223092/mark-longair) pointed before. The only problem I got was in the creation of the bare git repository. So let me resume how I solved it.

1. I already have my github private repository.
2. I created the EC2 Linux AMI (Ubuntu for practical procedures)
3. I've installed git, mysql, php, apache and ssh at the EC2 instance, and added my public ssh key to the `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.
4. Once at the EC2 instance I created two folders, the first one to hold the repository (I just named it as I've named my github repository), and the second one to hold the site(s): `mkdir sitesrepo.git websites`.
5. Then I went to the folder that was going to hold the repository and initialized the bare repository: `cd sitesrepo.git && git init --bare`
6. I created the hook file via vim with the following content in a file named `post-receive` and then I made it executable via `chmod +x post-receive` (just as the tutorial stated). That file must be placed at `/home/ubuntu/sitesrepo.git/hooks`

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/ubuntu/websites git checkout -f
   ```
7. Here's where my steps differ from the tutorial mentioned before: A bare git repository has a conflict where it can't hold the worktree being a bare repository (It doesn't make sense since it's a bare repository. Non-bare repositories are intended to have a working space, i.e. a worktree). Fortunately you can manually set up the repository `config` file. So by editing the file `/home/ubuntu/sitesrepo.git/config` you must guarantee to have something like this:

   ```
   [core]
       repositoryformatversion = 0
       filemode = true
       bare = false
       worktree = /home/ubuntu/websites
   [receive]
       denycurrentbranch = ignore
   ```
8. Now, at your own machine, at your git local repository working folder, the idea is to add a new remote repository. Currently you have configured by default `origin` which tells your repository to push your content into github's repository. The tutorial calls such remote repository `web`. So you have to run once: `git remote add web ssh://mysite.com/home/ubuntu/sitesrepo.git && git push web +master:refs/heads/master`. The subsequent pushes can be done via a simple `git push web`
9. Depending on how many sites you are planning to hold, you must [configure your apache `sites-enabled` hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387921/virtual-host-on-aws-ec2-running-ubuntu/16399932#16399932). Also, since you're using apache, don't forget to change the web folder to point to `/home/ubuntu/websites`, because by default it points to `/var/www` But you're ready to go, just don't forget to restart the apache service after defining the new web folder.

Hope this helps with your question.