# GIT post-receive hook to deploy appears to not be working

Tags: git, ubuntu

I am trying to use Git to push my files to my test server using the post-receive hook as described in this article:

http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto

There seems to be a lot of discussion over this and most seem to get it to work. My problem is that there is no post-receive.sample file in the /hooks dir so I am manually creating one. I have tried using the post-update file as well but I don't seem to be getting any results. My questions are:

1. Is there a log to that I can look at to see if anything is even running?
2. Is there a replacement for post-receive?

I am using Git v 1.7.9.5 on Ubuntu for the server and v 1.7.10 on Windows for the client.

Note: The push appears to be working just fine from the client side but it appears as though the checkout is not happening on the server.

Comment: There are two checkout levels on the server, one in a mirror of the repo, usually under your home directory, and another that is triggered from that checkout, that ends up in your doc-root.  Are both not happening? o9r just the doc-root one?

Comment: @Justin.Wood the $GIT_DIR is located in my home directory (/home/aarsan/projects/) and the $GIT_WORK_TREE is located in /var/www/. After I run the push from the client, I am checking to see if the files exist in /var/www/ but they don't. I really don't know what else I can do to verify if anything is running.

Comment: OK, do they exist in your home directory after the push though?  I ask because I am trying to determine if it is the hook that is failing or the push.

Comment: Take a look here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832586/setting-up-git-on-ec2-to-pull-from-github-repo/25095511#25095511